# Clearing my ajax form in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to clear the form if its submitted but the problem is my controller handles all the validation.

The AJAX response in contact.js.haml simply makes use of flashes not being defined if its invalid data.

```
/contact.js.haml
$("#new_message").replaceWith("#{j(render partial:'contact_mailer/contact_me', locals: {object: @message, notice: @notice} )}")
```

The controller sets the notice if needed

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.valid?
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Message was sent successfully.'
        ContactMailer.contact_me(@message)
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message was sent successfully.' }
        format.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      else
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path }
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is on a successful message send, the form still has the same data, allowing the user to spam it

I know this can be solved with JSON or XML to send the data but is there a way without!

*edit screenshot of reset() not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- if !@message.errors.any? 
  $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :hidden').val('')
```

haml didn't work before so I assumed it wouldn't but it did.

Answer (score 0):

A little cleaner: just `reset` the form (a plain javascript function).

In short:

```
$('form')[0].reset
```

This resets the first form on the page.

However, see this answer:[How come form.reset() doesn't work after postback on this page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267752/how-come-form-reset-doesnt-work-after-postback-on-this-page) It will reset the form to the values it received. And you send it from the server, *with values*!!!!

So the fix is dead-easy, in your `MessagesController` write

```
def contact
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.valid?
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Message was sent successfully.'
      ContactMailer.contact_me(@message)
      @message = Message.new
      format.html { redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message was sent successfully.' }
      format.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    else
      format.html { redirect_to contact_path }
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

So before rendering, start with a fresh, new message, and your form will be ok :)

On a general note: your naming and grouping is generally very confusing and not very structured. You should work on that.

Comment: Oddly this doesn't always work for some reason see screenshot above

Comment: Are you sure the id is `new_message`? Because when you are editing it will become `edit_message` (and the error indicates the form with id `new_message` is not found). You could always assign a class, or if there is only one form, use just `$('form')`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, after the ajax call .reset no longer functions even using the $('form') tested multiple times

Comment: And `$('form')[0]` is defined? And it is the only form? `$('form').length()` should be 1? Otherwise you could be resetting the wrong form? (or a hidden form?). Just guessing, a bit hard to help/tell without any code. The `replaceWith` would normally not leave any dangling forms, but could change the id easily (since it replaces the complete div).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the error is. Length is 1 form[0] defined. Git is https://github.com/Snowfiring/Mika if you wan't to see the code. I tried it out in the console