# Reset of a form after submission yield submitted values and not default ones

Tags: javascript, flask, wtforms

I have a question dealing with reset of forms after submission. The problem has definitely been discussed earlier. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267752/how-come-form-reset-doesnt-work-after-postback-on-this-page).

Here the Flask form (that uses `wtforms`):

```
field = DecimalField(default=0.0, validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=2)])

class AForm(Form):
    ff1=field

class BForm(Form):
    ff2=FieldList(FormField(AForm), min_entries=4)
```

**Update**: here the Flask view

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_form():
    form = BForm(request.form)
    D=form.ff2.entries
    L=0
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        for entry in D:
            L+=entry.ff1.data
        return render_template('test_stack.html', form=form, L=L)
    return render_template('test_stack.html', form=form, L=L)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And here the main part of the template, which renders the form (**updated**):

```
<form action="/test" id="myForm" method=post>
        <table>
            <tr>
            {% for field in form.ff2 %}
                <th>
                    {{ field.ff1 }}
                </th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table> 
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="calc">
    <span id="result"> {{ L }} </span>
    <input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" ></input>
</form>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
           ....
        });
    });      
</script>
```

My *problem* is the following:

While the reset button works fine before submission, it does not after. After submission, default values become those which have been submitted and no longer those defined in the form. In other words, when one modifies entry values and then clicks on reset, previously submitted values are restored and not the default ones.

My *question* is :

What should I do, in order to have a reset button that allows to restore the original default values defined in the form ? Thanks for your help.

Please consider that I've simplified the code given above, whereas the real one contains many different fields, each having its own default value.

Comment: From your given code it's hard to tell how exactly your form is populated, how it is submitted. It's also not clear what the role of that click event handler is (`$(document).ready` inside it looks strange). Providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas Thanks for your comment. I have given now the entire code the poses problems. Hope that's enough. You're also right concerning the click event handler, which should be filled by something (written as it is now, it's indeed useless).
I would finally point out that my concern is how to have a reset button that restores default values, defined in the form.

Comment: The first answer in your linked question explains this rather well. On submit you send the form back, and its current values become default values (see `value` attributes in rendered HTML). I doubt you can do anything without using JavaScript, e.g. rendering default values as a JSON object in your HTML and then "resetting" from it in Reset button click handler.